# Tool for checking unused javascript plugins

Tags: javascript, version-control, code-coverage

I have inherited a javascript project which is referencing a lot of 3rd party plugin scripts, some of which, aren't used at all.  Is there a tool out there which can check the codebase and flag plugins that aren't being referenced at all? That way I can delete them with confidence.

I'm trying to get the project nice and lean to take forwards.

Comment: See Google Closure in Advanced Mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the project has code that's fired on user interaction, then I doubt you'll find a tool to do it for you. Having said that, most IDE's have tools to find unused code (code that isn't being referenced in your project) such as 'inspect code' in intelliJ.

To do it manually, you could add breakpoints in dev tools on the methods in the libs, if they don't fire you know your not using them
(but again make sure code triggered by user interaction is tested too)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Looks like a thorough manual testing is needed for this first step and hopefully can get it more automated moving forwards.  I'm reading up on tools available in Webstorm now, too. Thanks again.